# How to add a js file to component.html in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular-cli

I am migrating a header that is in html and javaScript, how can I reference this java script file in `app.component.html`?

I already imported this file in `angular.json` in scripts.

```html
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/app/_utils/mainHeader.js"
            ]
```

How to add a js file to component.html in angular 8?

Comment: Firstly you should not use jquery with Angular, that is not recommended. Also if mainHeader is required to be used within the header, i'd recommend copy the funcs of that in the header component.

Comment: "i'd recommend copy the funcs of that in the header component", How would you do it technically?

Comment: Are there many many functions in mainHeader.js ?

Comment: Every js code is a valid TS code. The code of mainHeader can be moved to component.ts file.

Comment: approximately 600 lines of code

Comment: Can I start use inside the ngOnInit ? @ Sagar Agrawal